# Openldap logs not getting generated

Tags: linux, logging, openldap

I have been trying to enable logging in my OpenLDAP setup (in Oracle Enterprise Linux 6.5) , but no logs are being generated in /var/log/slapd/slapd.log.

Followed these steps to enable logging :

1. Edited the slapd.conf file :

**# grep -i loglevel /etc/openldap/slapd.conf**

**loglevel -1**

2. Did the setup for the log directory in /var/log/slapd
   **# cd /var/log/slapd ; ls -ltr**

**-rw------- 1 root root 217 May 21 19:48 slapd.log**

3. Edited the rsyslog config file

**# grep -i local4 /etc/rsyslog.conf**

**local4.*                            /var/log/slapd/slapd.log**

4. restarted the openldap service and also the rsyslogger :

**# service rsyslog restart**

**# service slapd restart**

But even after doing these steps , we are not seeing logs captured in the slapd.log file . Only log seen is the below line :

**more /var/log/slapd/slapd.log**

May 21 19:48:12 sprdneval slapd[2961]: @(#) $OpenLDAP: slapd 2.4.39 (Aug 16 2014 20:41:55) $#012#011mockbuild@ca-buildj3.us
.oracle.com:/builddir/build/BUILD/openldap-2.4.39/openldap-2.4.39/build-servers/servers/slapd

Am i missing to do something blindingly obvious ?

Regards,
Hari

Comment: Are you using the online configuration? If so, the settings are in LDAP itself. It's worth also checking if the logs are in a different log file: `grep -R slapd /var/log/*`

Comment: Yes, that one. Have a look here http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/slapd-config.html. Hopefully the distribution won't matter. Other question, what user is running the daemon?

Comment: Checked grep -R slapd /var/log/* but nothing substantial. I do not know much of olc . Can that be utilised for logging ?

Comment: OLC is the same as a configuration file (but you use one of the two, config file or olc), with the difference that the configuration is in a ldap DIT and can be modified on the fly. For instance, in my distro it was enable by default. Can you see a directory `/etc/openldap/slapd.d`?

Comment: Ok got it . i can see slapd.d directory . This might have come default in my distro as i had never done the slapd.conf to slapd.d conversion myself.                                                                                                   `# ls -lrt /etc/openldap/slapd.d`
`drwx------ 3 ldap ldap 4096 Apr  9 13:37 cn=config`
`-rw------- 1 ldap ldap 1281 Apr  9 13:38 cn=config.ldif`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the OnLine Configuration (OLC) have a look at [Zytrax](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/slapd-config.html). It explains quite well how to use and configure it.

Comment: Yes , i have started reading [Zytrax](http://www.zytrax.com/books/ldap/ch6/slapd-config.html) but have not found yet any mention on enabling logging.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here ('loglevel any' and 'logfile /var/log/slapd/slapd.log' options in slapd.conf and in the cn=config, but no debug output in the logfile).

I've just solved the problem by adding "-d any" to the command line arguments of the slapd

```
/usr/bin/slapd -d any -u ldap -g ldap -h "ldap://127.0.0.1/ ldaps:/// ldapi:///"
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the same issue and posted my question at [Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/1086071/211024) about what '-s' option means.

If you see olcLogLevel setting at current config:

```
$ sudo grep olcLogLevel /etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config.ldif
olcLogLevel: 0
```

Then, you can change it by:

```
$ sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// <<EOF
dn:           cn=config
changetype:   modify
replace:      olcLogLevel
olcLogLevel:  256
EOF
```

If you don't see olcLogLevel setting, then you need to newly create the entry.  I haven't seen the case but I think it will be done by change 'changetype' above from 'modify' to 'add'.

My environment is CentOS7.9 so that the path would be different from yours.

Answer (score -1):

You can do and check `df -h` to check disk space and delete heavy files which you do not require (like `messages*.gz`) from `/var/log/` also empty the content of `/var/log/slapd/slapd.log`

Now you reboot your system and check service `slapd` status.

Hope ,it works now.

Comment: The question is about the logs not being generated at all. While this is technically an answer that could be possible, it is clear from the original question that this isn't the problem.